# WidgetBase with Ajax Callback and manipulate #tree values

Tags: 8, entities, ajax

After many tries, maybe someone can help me here. I want a dynamic form field in a widget base, but I keep having problems.

1st Values of the submit button are lost after submit and can´t manipulate the value of 'object_qt'. I thougt, they where handled in massageFormValue and saved in extractFormValues, but it´s not changing and if I save the Node, the values are lost. I have Found here some other Posts, but nothing works for me.

2nd The ajax callback doesn`t work for the types 'button' or 'submit'. Always the whole page loads without any changes.

In Widgetbase.php are the add more Option and also tested it for my TestWidget, but run into the same issues.

```
class TestWidget extends WidgetBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement( 
    FieldItemListInterface $items, 
    $delta, 
    array $element, 
    array &$form,
    FormStateInterface $form_state
  ) {

    $element['object_pos'] = [
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Pos'),
      '#attributes' => [
        'id' => 'position-'.$delta,
      ],
    ];

    $defaultObjectQt = isset($items[$delta]->object_qt) ? $items[$delta]->object_qt :  0;

    $posItems = is_numeric($defaultObjectQt) && $defaultObjectQt > 0 ? $defaultObjectQt : 1;
    $element['object_pos'] += TestWidget::formPos($items, $delta, $posItems);

    $element['object_qt'] = [
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#default_value' => $defaultObjectQt,
    ];

    $element['object_qt_wrapper'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',

      'object_qt_more' => [
        '#title' => t('Qt'),
        '#type' => 'number',
        '#empty_value' => '',
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#size' => 2,
      ],
      'object_qt_add' => [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('add more'),
        // '#ajax' => [
        //   'callback' => [$this, 'rebuildPos'], // dosn`t work
        //   'event' => 'change',
        //   'wrapper' => 'position-'.$delta,
        //   'progress' => [
        //     'type' => 'throbber',
        //     'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
        //   ],
        // ],
      ],
    ];

    return $element;
  }

  public function massageFormValues(array $values, array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    foreach($values as $itemKey => $itemValue) {
        if(!empty($itemValue['object_pos'])) {
          $values[$itemKey]['object_pos'] = serialize($itemValue['object_pos']);
        };
        // Manipulate values
    };

    return $values;
  }


  public function rebuildPos(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
    $element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();

    $delta = $element['#parents'][1];
    $posItems = $element['#value'];

    $posElement = ObjectReferenceWidget::formPos($items, $delta, $posItems);
    $ergebnis = array_merge($form['field_object_reference']['widget'][$delta], $posElement['object_pos']);

    return $ergebnis['object_pos'];

  }

  public function formPos($items, $delta, int &$posItems) {

    $posArray = [];
    for($i=0; $i < $posItems; $i++) {
      $posArray['item-'.$i] = [];
    };

    // get defaults
    if(!empty($items[$delta]->object_pos)) {  
      $posValues = unserialize($items[$delta]->object_pos);
      //$posArray = array_merge( $posArray, $posValues);
    };

    foreach($posArray as $itemKey => $itemValue) {
      $element['object_pos'][$itemKey] = [
        'coords' => [

          // ... form fields

        ],  
      ];


    };

    return $element;
  }
```

Comment: You're adding elements in your Ajax callback. They won't work. They need to be added in the for definition.

Comment: Do you have an example of the widget base? I have seen your comments in several posts, but nowhere a clear solution and since the structure of Drupal 8 is much more extensive, it is difficult to find the right start.

Comment: I don't have an example with WidgetBase, but bein in WidgetBase is irrelevant - the premise is the same with all Form API #ajax; form elements must be added in the form definition, not in the AjaxCallback. There are literally hundreds of topics on Drupal Answers alone with the same issue, same reply.

Comment: ok, but the callback doesn`t work. Normaly there is an error message in the console. I got nothing and the page reloads. In the ajax callback I have now only these both lines:     $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE); return $form['object_pos'];
With the number field I got the error message: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\AjaxRenderer::renderResponse() must be of the type array, null given,

Comment: Setting the form to rebuild must happen in a submit handler, it will not work in an ajax callback.